# What exactly does Sauron speak in "The Battle of the Five Armies"?

Tags: movie, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, sauron

According to sources about *[Black Speech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashi_(Black_Speech))*, there was a single line invented for the LotR movies (the one where Sauron tells Frodo that there's no life in void).

However, in *The Battle of the Five Armies* (at approximately 27 minutes) there are many samples of Black Speech by Sauron.

When he taunts Galadriel that she's "the only light, alone in the darkness" (according to the subtitles), what is heard is actually "ashi, burzum ishi" ("the only [one] in darkness").

**Is there a full transcript of Sauron's speech in the Dol Guldur scene, up to the moment when Sauron is banished?**

Comment: the dialog there was entirely invented for the movie, and no transcript exists that I know of. The best we have at the moment is this information from the guy who invented the languages that are original to the movies: http://midgardsmal.com/category/blackspeech/.  Perhaps we'll get more when the DVD box sets start coming out.

Comment: He talks trash, but Galadriel promptly puts him in his place!

Comment: I think it's one of the Ringwraiths who taunt Galadriel not Sauron

Comment: Also being discussed at [Movies.SE]: [What is Sauron saying when Galadriel defeats him at Dol Guldur?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34416/what-is-sauron-saying-when-galadriel-defeats-him-at-dol-guldur)

Answer (score 3):

According to the movie subtitles, he says:

> "It has begun.The east will fall.
>
> So shall the Kingdom of Angmar rise.
>
> The time of the Elves is over.
>
> The Age of the Orc has come. "

Comment: Thanks, I also read subtitles. However, I asked for Black speech transcript, not for translation.

Comment: Is it odd that Sauron would say "The age of the Orc"? I'd expect him to be more selfish.

Comment: @Hatandboots  I think he's going for parallelism with the previous line.  "Sauron" isn't a race, so he's comparing Elves to Orcs.  It's like an American saying "The age of the Old World is ending, it's time for the New World to take over."  They would be referring to the United States specifically, rather than all of North/South America, but using a more general term because it fits the comparison more poetically.

Comment: Shouldn't it be west, and not east?

Comment: @Hatandboots Orcs are as good as an extension of Sauron's will. So when he says age of the orc, he means "my age"

Comment: @maguirenumber6 Angmar led by Witchking, if I'm not wrong, in The Second Age, conquered West. If you look at the Tolkiens map in the book of Unfinished tales, you can see that on the West of Middle Earth it says the Lost Realm of Arnor, an old Kingdom of men, like Gondor in the East. So there are no kingdoms of men in the East in the Third Age.

Answer (score 2):

First lines are the beginning of the Ring-verse:
Shre nazg golugranu kilmi nudur,
Ombi Kuzddurbagu gundum-ishi bagu.

Then goes: 
Dunni kan markhan. Omidi-shu. Ashi burzum-ishi.

But the last words I also haven't been able to find :(

Comment: I think he's specifically asking about the parts we don't already know :) Also.. the way the scene plays out, I don't think Sauron is the one who says this part.

Comment: Correct. Thanks for 'Omidi-shu', but is most interesting is the rest - when Sauron appears like huge red eye with visions passing over, until Galadriel banishes him.

Comment: Looks Turkish-like to me. The quotation that was quoted, I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I searched and found various sources and according to them, the transcript of Sauron's Dol Guldur speech goes like this:
Shre nazg golugranu kilmi nudur
-"Three rings for the Elven Kings under the sky"
Ombi kuzddurbagu gundum-ishi (bagu)
-"seven for the dwarf lords in their halls of stone"

Dunni kan markhan
-"You cannot fight the shadow"
Omidi-shu
-"Even now you fade"
Ashi burzum-ishi
-"One light alone in the darkness"

Iz er garan
-"It has begun"
Bur ghan-maszh
-"the East will fall"
Dazb Angmu gul-liz ash
-"So shall the kingdom of Angmar rise"
Dag bur-shur nurb Ainur
-"The time of the Elves is over"
Burz-khan im bro
-"The Age of the Orc has come"

Comment: Which sources are these and where did you find them?